# Total of an array using class object

Tags: c++, class

How can I get the total of the grosspay of all five employees? I've tried everything including creating objects but none seem to work, also I must store all the data in one array called EmpData so I cannot change that. I require assistance. This is the code I've created and it runs and works properly so far.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class Employee {
private:
    double hourswrk;
    double payrate;
    double grosspay;
    int empno;
    char empname[20];
    double netpay;
    double tax;
    double overt;
    double overtime;
    double taxdeduct;

public:
    void getdetails();
    void calculatepay();
    void showdetails();
};
void Employee::getdetails()
{
    cout << "\nEnter employee name:\n";
    cin >> empname;
    cout << "\nEnter employee number:\n";
    cin >> empno;
    cout << "Enter hours worked:";
    cin >> hourswrk;
    cout << "Enter rate of pay";
    cin >> payrate;
}
void Employee::calculatepay()
{
    tax = 0.25;
    overt = 1.5;
    if(hourswrk >= 60)
    {
        grosspay = 0;
        netpay = 0;
        taxdeduct = 0;

        cout << "You have exceeded the amount of hours!";
    }
    else if(hourswrk <= 40)
    {
        grosspay = hourswrk * payrate;
    }
    else if(hourswrk > 40 && hourswrk < 60)
    {
        overtime = hourswrk - 40;
        grosspay = overt * payrate*overtime + hourswrk * payrate;
    }
    taxdeduct = tax * grosspay;
    netpay = grosspay - taxdeduct;
}

void Employee::showdetails()
{
    cout << "Employee Payslip\n";
    cout << "Name: " << empname;
    cout << "Employee number:" << empno;
    cout << "Basic Salary" << payrate;
    cout << "Hours work" << hourswrk;
    cout << "Grosspay" << grosspay;
    cout << "Tax: " << taxdeduct;
    cout << "Net Salary" << netpay;
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Employee EmpData[5];
    int i;
    double hourswrk;
    double payrate;
    double grosspay;
    int empno;
    char empname[20];
    double netpay;
    double tax = 0.25;
    double taxdeduct;
    double overt = 1.5;
    double overtime;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        EmpData[i].getdetails();
        EmpData[i].calculatepay();
        EmpData[i].showdetails();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: gah! formatting please

Comment: No there is no error, I just need to find the total grosspay generated by all the five employees

Comment: @Naya What have you tried? Other than asking someone else to try for you?

Comment: What is your input? What is the expected output? What is the output or error message you got?

Comment: I have tried to create five objects but that gave me a null error, I've tried creating a function but I still get a null error. I must input five employee's names, numbers hours worked and payrate, the program successfully calculated the grosspay and netpay but I have to find the total grosspay of the five employees and output it.

Comment: I also outputted the name,employee number,payrate,tax charged,netpay etc but after that I have to find the total of the grosspay that was calculated

Comment: Not getting paid at all if you work more than 60 hours seems very unfair.

Answer (score 1):

i just added a global variable which has `totgrosspay`  every time you enter `grosspay`  `grosspay` is added to `totgrosspay`

```
    #include<iostream>
     long totgrosspay=0;
    using namespace std;
    class Employee {
    private: 
        long grosspay=0;
        double hourswrk;
        double payrate;
        int empno;
        char empname[20];
        double netpay;
        double tax;
        double overt;
        double overtime;
        double taxdeduct;

    public:
        void getdetails();
        void calculatepay();
        void showdetails();

    };
    void Employee::getdetails()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter employee name:\n";
        cin >> empname;
        cout << "\nEnter employee number:\n";
        cin >> empno;
        cout << "Enter hours worked:";
        cin >> hourswrk;
        cout << "Enter rate of pay";
        cin >> payrate;

    }
    void Employee::calculatepay()
    {
        tax = 0.25;
        overt = 1.5;
        if(hourswrk >= 60)
        {
            grosspay = 0;
            netpay = 0;
            taxdeduct = 0;

            cout << "You have exceeded the amount of hours!";
        }
        else if(hourswrk <= 40)
        {
            grosspay = hourswrk * payrate;
        }
        else if(hourswrk > 40 && hourswrk < 60)
        {
            overtime = hourswrk - 40;
            grosspay = overt * payrate*overtime + hourswrk * payrate;
        }
        taxdeduct = tax * grosspay;
        netpay = grosspay - taxdeduct;
        totgrosspay= totgrosspay+grosspay;
    }

    void Employee::showdetails()
    {
        cout << "Employee Payslip\n";
        cout << "Name: " << empname;
        cout << "Employee number:" << empno;
        cout << "Basic Salary" << payrate;
        cout << "Hours work" << hourswrk;
        cout << "Grosspay" << grosspay;
        cout << "Tax: " << taxdeduct;
        cout << "Net Salary" << netpay;
        cout << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        Employee EmpData[5];
        int i;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            EmpData[i].getdetails();
            EmpData[i].calculatepay();
            EmpData[i].showdetails();

        }
        cout<<totgrosspay;// it prints gross pay value
        system("pause");

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Getting an error, I've already outputted the grosspay, I have to total all five grosspays that was calculated

Comment: Yes but the total grosspay generated by all five employees, the program already calculates and displays the gross pay for each employee. I have to total those five grosspays and output it

Comment: it's outputting "4.200/n/n"

Comment: getting 6.1692e

Comment: now try in this worst way for testing make variables public  & `cout<<"total grosspay="<<EmpData[1].grosspay+EmpData[2].grosspay+ EmpData[3].grosspay+EmpData[4].grosspay;` **for testing purpose only**

Comment: make it public:

Comment: @Naya: to mark this as solved, please click the tick mark adjacent to the answer. We don't use [solved] devices in titles here, as we have a full acceptance system.